# vue.js: vue-multiselect, clearing input value after selected

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am working on my project in laravel/vue.js and I decided to use simple vue-multiselect to choose categories from my database. Thing is I want to clear the value from input field (to look for item in list).

My multiselect component:

```
<multiselect 
    v-model="value" 
    placeholder="Find the category" 
    label="category_name"
    :options="categories"
    @input="addReceiversFromCategory">
</multiselect>
```

I try to clear an v-model but it work only on first select after page load (and also it is not a smart way..).
Last thing i try was the `:clear-on-select="true"` but it works onlu when multiple is true (which I dont want to be true).
I think its simple to do but I didn't find any way in documentation [doc](https://monterail.github.io/vue-multiselect/)

Answer (score -3):

If your `v-model` is just modeling the value selected, then you need to use that value however you want and reset `value` to null. I don't really know how your component is set up but it would look something like this:

```
<template>
  <select v-model="value" v-on:change="doSomething()">
    <option :value="null">-- Select --</option>
    <option value="foo">Foo</option>
    <option value="bar">Bar</option>
  </select>
</template>

<script>
  module.exports = {
    data: function(){
      return {
        value: null
      };
    },
    methods: {
      doSomething: function() {
        if( this.value ) {
          var data = this.value; // now you can work with data
          this.value = null; // reset the select to null
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: `this.value = null;` does not reset the v-model data to empty.